# jQuery-Mobile: MultiPage template loads but is dead

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a single page template page (`page1.aspx`) which loads a multi-page template page (`page2.aspx`)

The Multi-page template page has buttons which show internal pages as dialogs. When `page1` loads `page2` via the default AJAX behavior, the buttons on page2 do not work. Forcing a refresh of `page2` in the browser lets the buttons on page2 work.

If I add `data-ajax="false"` to my links in page1, all is fine.

How do I have a multi-page template page load via AJAX so that buttons on it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot link to a multi-page document via AJAX. Only the first `data-role="page"` element will be imported into the DOM and everything else will be ignored (even content in the `<head>`).

If you link to the multi-page template without AJAX then the whole page will load and all of the `data-role="page"` elements will be available. To do this you can set attributes on specific links like this:

```
<a hef="#" data-ajax="false">my link</a>
```

Or like this:

```
<a hef="#" rel="external">my link</a>
```

You can also set this option globally like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

I have seen a plugin that allows you to do what you want, but I have not been able to find it. It just pulls all the `data-role="page"` elements in from the multi-page document rather than just the first one (it seems to me that this would create some strange deep-linking issues however).

**UPDATE**

*Oh, and it's a good one :)*

With version 1.0, jQuery Mobile will let you pre-fetch pages by adding the `data-prefetch="true"` attribute to links. If you split your multi-page template into separate pages, you can then pre-fetch them so they will be added to the DOM and appear "instantly" when the link to them is clicked (rather than waiting for the AJAX request to resolve).

Docs for prefetching: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Comment: Is there anyway to reload 1 page from your multi-page template? For example: file1 has page #A and #B in it. On pagehide I remove page #A from the DOM and to the same when pagehide occurs on page #B. When I go back to page #A it is reloaded, but the link to page #B doesn't work anymore. Is there any way, or is it best to just split the template?

Comment: In that circumstance it will be best to split the template into two separate files. Remember to include all JS and CSS files in each document so a refresh won't ruin your visitor's experience. To do this with a multi-page template you would still have to use AJAX (to grab another copy of the same document). Also, if you use separate files then when you navigate away from a page it will be automatically removed from the DOM.